# isset and empty is not fixing the undefined index notice, this causes not to update my data in sql

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update, undefined

I did a research, I've already initialized an isset and empty function but it's not helping to solve the undefined index, because of this, I can't update all my data in sql, even the images are not showing and updating, any other solution for this?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

session_start();
include("../db_connection.php");


if(empty($_POST['food_id'])) {

var_dump($_POST);
 $food_id = $_POST['food_id'];
$seller_id = $_SESSION['seller_id'];
$food_name = $_POST['food_name'];
$f_price = $_POST ['f_price'];
$f_ingredients = $_POST ['f_ingredients'];
$f_status = $_POST['f_status'];
$date_posted = $_POST ['date_posted'];
$time_posted = $_POST ['time_posted'];

$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['f_image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $sql = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE 'food_product'
                    SET
                    food_id = '$food_id',
                    food_name = '$food_name',
                    f_price = '$f_price',
                    f_ingredients = '$f_ingredients',
                    f_status = '$f_status',
                    date_posted = '$date_posted',
                    time_posted = '$time_posted'
                    WHERE food_id='$food_id'");
    if ($sql)
    {

        $id = mysqli_insert_id($db);
        $filename = $id.'.'.$extension;

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['f_image']['tmp_name'], 'food_upload/'.$filename))
        {
            mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE food_product
                                SET f_image = '$filename' 
                                WHERE food_id = '$id' ");
        }   

        header('location: seller_menu.php');

    }
    else
    {

        mysqli_error($db);
    }   
 }
?>
```

Comment: `if (!empty($_POST['food_id']))`

Comment: Where is your isset and empty condition ?

Comment: What is the error your getting (and where)?

Comment: @NigelRen I got undefined Index: food_id

Answer (score 0):

Where is isset and !empty in your code u can't see

Replace this

```
if(empty($_POST['food_id'])) {
.........
}
```

with

```
  if(!empty($_POST['food_id'])) {
          ......
      }
```

for rest of data if all is not required at form level

```
$food_name = isset($_POST['food_name']) && !empty($_POST['food_name']) ? $_POST['food_name'] : "" ;

$f_price =  isset($_POST['f_price']) && !empty($_POST['f_price']) ? $_POST['f_price'] : "" ;

$f_ingredients =  isset($_POST['f_ingredients']) && !empty($_POST['f_ingredients']) ? $_POST['f_ingredients'] : ""; 

$f_status = isset($_POST['f_status']) && !empty($_POST['f_status']) ? $_POST['f_status'] : ""; 

$date_posted = isset($_POST['date_posted']) && !empty($_POST['date_posted']) ? $_POST['date_posted'] : ""; 

$time_posted = isset($_POST['time_posted']) && !empty($_POST['time_posted']) ? $_POST['time_posted'] : "";
```

Comment: Using both `isset` and `empty` is __redundant__.

Comment: I got a blank page sir